# Is it possible to include the file extension when selecting files by typing in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

Say I have four files [`a.test1`, `a.test2`, `a.test3`, `a.test4`], if I type `a` it will select `a.test1`; however, is there a way I can type `a.test3` and have it select that file? To be more specific, I am not referring to Windows search and that is not what I want. If you click some where in Windows Explorer and start typing, it will select the file matching what you type. I am wondering if I could also include the file extension while doing this.

Edit: it appears that this is already possible but it doesn't work if the file extension is hidden, e.g. with a pdf file. The option to show file extensions must be enabled for it to work in this case. I am wondering if it is possible to do it without this option enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the answer is "no", at least not without third-party tools of some kind that I'm unaware of.

The feature you're speaking of is a bit under-used and under-documented, and not many people know about it, a kind of "jump to". Think about it this way, if you had the files:

```
ab.exe
az.exe
bc.com
cd.com
cd.bat
cz.dat
```

you could surface "cd.bat" by typing "cd.b" - think of it as typing into an invisible autocomplete. But, as you've found, this is one way only, from the start of the filename. There's no way to surface the only `dat` file in this directory with this method.

Comment: I think my question was still unclear. Including the file extension at the end rather than just specifying the file extension was what I meant. Anyway, from my testing I was only able to do this with the "File Name Extensions" option enabled if the file extensions were hidden. Would it possible to do it without that option enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Type the file-name in the Search box of Explorer, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
and it will be displayed.

You could also use an alternate file-manager, such as
[Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/)
(free).

Comment: To be more specific, I am not referring to Windows search and that is not what I want. If you click some where in Windows Explorer and start typing, it will select the file matching what you type. I am wondering if I could also specify the file extension while doing this.

Comment: You can do that in Salamander (and I do that frequently). Explorer will only match the first character.